# How to associate provenance information to an ExecuteSQL result in NiFi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm executing a series of queries after listing tables in a database, basically doing database dumps with some smarts added.

When the data comes out of the `ExecuteSql` processor, it's in Avro format. I can use `ConvertAvroToJson` to, uh, convert to JSON. I can then send that JSON elsewhere. Great!

However, I need more information embedded in that JSON document. I minimally want:

1. the name of the table on which the query was executed,
2. database DSN (sans credentials, probably hardcoded into the config because I don't think it's accessible from NiFi expression language fields),
3. the query executed that generated the record,
4. the record number within the query set (the total number of rows is already an attribute).
5. Arbitrary information pulled from environment variables or a config file, falling back to a hardcoded in an `UpdateAttributes` processor otherwise

`ExecuteSQL` doesn't seem to provide this information but [it does seem to *copy* attributes from the input flowfile](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/ExecuteSQL.java#L214). I might be able to put some of this information into the input flowfile attributes via an `UpdateAttributes` earlier in the pipeline. If that is possible, how can I merge the JSON output from `ExecuteSQL -> ConvertAvroToJSON` with the attributes, feasibly output from the `AttributesToJson` processor?

Comment: I'm really trying to avoid writing my own processors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of comments:

1) Are you using [ListDatabaseTables](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.4.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListDatabaseTables/index.html) first? If so, you will have attributes on your flow file including table name, database name, etc.

2) This information isn't currently available to a processor, the DBCPService API only exposes a JDBC [Connection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html). Perhaps you could use a scripted processor like ExecuteScript to execute the SQL (I have an example on [my blog](http://funnifi.blogspot.in/2016/04/sql-in-nifi-with-executescript.html)) and get access to the metadata, but I'm not sure it would have all the info you want. The provenance for this processor will also not have the information, as we are not storing a Transit URI for the provenance event. We should consider making at least the Transit URI (minus sensitive values) available to the processor.

3) If you are hard-coding the SQL query in the ExecuteSQL processor, you can also hard-code it into an attribute using UpdateAttribute beforehand. If the flow file contains the SQL query, you can use [ExtractText](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.4.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExtractText/index.html) to put it into an attribute. We should also enhance the processor to add the query as an attribute (would have to be optional since some queries can be pretty large).

4) Are you looking to have each record split with its "row number" as an attribute? After [SplitAvro](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-avro-nar/1.4.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.avro.SplitAvro/index.html) you would have a fragment.index attribute which would be a zero-based number associated with each record.

5) You can use Expression Language in UpdateAttribute, so in combination with a [Variable Registry](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/57304/supporting-custom-properties-for-expression-langua.html) you could read values from environment variables or a registry file. You may also be interested in [PropertiesFileLookupService](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-lookup-services-nar/1.4.0/org.apache.nifi.lookup.PropertiesFileLookupService/index.html).